# How can i send email with dynamic html content?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I am sending simple html templated emails to users, now i want to include text box and submit button in my email template. user can put text in textbox in email and submit data, that data will save in my database. How can i do this? any suggestions?

Comment: Forms are not well supported in html email. Support chart [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/). Either of the two answers below are the only way to do it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a link in your email content to redirect on the form in browser.

Look on this website to understand why put a form in an email is not good way : [Send a Form via Email](http://email.about.com/cs/usingemail/a/email_forms.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Add a link to redirect them to browser form is nicer, and you can add some variable at the URL to recognize the user too like http://testingsite.com/form?user=xxx, so that u can know who is the user and pre-filled date or them.